# Linux character device driver issues

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, linux-kernel, kernel-modules

I am writing a LKM to create a character device driver.

Linux Kernel: 4.4.0-93-generic in VirtualBox, 2GB ram and SWAP is 300Kb

#### Problem 1

If I write a C program that handles the **fd** in dev_write, it's all good, it reads as it should, but if I try to use **head -n 1 < /dev/opsysmem** it does not output anything.

Code for reading from device:

```
int main()
{
    int ret, fd;
    char stringToSend[BUFFER_LENGTH];
    printf("Starting device test code example...\n");
    fd = open("/dev/opsysmem", O_RDWR); // Open the device with read/write access
    if (fd < 0)
    {
        perror("Failed to open the device...");
        return errno;
    }

    printf("Press ENTER to read back from the device...\n");
    getchar();

    printf("Reading from the device...\n");
    ret = read(fd, receive, BUFFER_LENGTH); // Read the response from the LKM
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        perror("Failed to read the message from the device.");
        return errno;
    }
    printf("The received message is: [%s]\n", receive);

    return 0;
}
```

#### Problem 2

If I repeatedly send a message big enough, everything is fine, my 2MiB buffer fills up and then the following messages are discarded. However, if the message is smaller (i.e 1 char each), it stops after about 10000 nodes. Is this a problem with my implementation of the linked list, a known linux problem or it's just me not observing something in my code?

When I encounter Problem 2, the vCPU throttles in sinusoidal manner

Here are my functions for read, write:

```
static ssize_t dev_read(struct file *filep, char *buffer, size_t len, loff_t *offset) {
    Node *msg;
    int ret_val;
    char* message;
    unsigned int message_length;

    // Entering critical section
    down(&sem); //wait state

    msg = pop(&l, 0);

    // No message? No wait!
    if(!msg) {
        up(&sem);
        return -EAGAIN;
    }

    if(len < msg->length) {
        up(&sem);
        return -EINVAL;
    }

    // Since we have a message, let's send it!
    current_size -= message_length;

    // copy_to_user has the format ( * to, *from, size) and returns 0 on success
    ret_val = copy_to_user(buffer, msg->string, message_length);

    if (!ret_val) {
        remove_element(&l, 0);
        up(&sem);
        return ret_val;
    } else {
        up(&sem);
        return -EFAULT; // Failed
    }
}


static ssize_t dev_write(struct file *filep, const char *buffer, size_t len, loff_t *offset) {
    Node *n;

    // buffer larger than 2 * 1024 bytes
    if(len > MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE || len == 0) {
        return -EINVAL;
    }

    n = kmalloc(sizeof(Node), GFP_KERNEL);

    if(!n) { 
        return -EAGAIN;
    }

    n->string = (char*) kmalloc(len, GFP_KERNEL);
    n->length = len;

    copy_from_user(n->string, buffer, len);

    // Enter critical section
    down(&sem); //wait state
    if(SLEEP) msleep(100);

    // buffer is larger than the total list memory (2MiB)
    if(current_size + len > MAX_LIST_SIZE) {
        up(&sem);
        return -EAGAIN;
    }

    current_size += len;

    push(&l, n);

    up(&sem);
    // Exit critical section

    return len;
}
```

And here is my linked list and its functions

```
typedef struct Node {
    unsigned int length;
    char* string;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

typedef struct list{
    struct Node *node;
} list;

static void init(list * l){
    l->node = NULL;
}

static void destroyNode(Node *n) {
    if(n) {
        destroyNode(n->next);
        kfree(n->string);
        n->string = NULL;
        kfree(n);
        n = NULL;
    }
}

static void destroy(list *l){
    if(l) {
        destroyNode(l->node);
    }
}

static Node* pop(list *l, unsigned int index) {
    struct Node *_current = l->node;

    // Cut down index until reaching the desired position
    while(_current) {
        if(index) {
            _current = _current->next;
            index--;
        } else { return _current; }
    }

    // If you are here, the node does not exist
    return NULL;
}

static int push(list * l, Node *n) {
    if(!n) { return -1; }

    // Initialize the string

    // Do we have a node in the list?
    if (l->node) { 
        // Virtually add it as a head
        n->next = l->node;
    } else {
        n->next = NULL;
    } // Otherwise prepare the list to have no tail

    // Now make the list point to the head
    l->node = n;

    return 0;
}

static int remove_element(list * l, unsigned int index){
    // Get the reference for head
    struct Node *previous;
    struct Node *_current;

    previous = NULL;
    _current = (Node*) l->node;

    // Swap _current until index
    while(_current) {
        // Is the index !0 and we have more nodes?
        if(index) {
            previous = _current;
            _current = _current->next;
            index--;
        } else {
            if(previous) {
                previous->next = _current->next;
            } else {
                l->node = _current->next;
            }
            // Free memory, assign NULL pointer
            kfree(_current->string);
            _current-> string = NULL;
            kfree(_current);
            _current = NULL;

            // Return success
            return 0;
        }
    }

    // No _current? No problem!
    return -1;
}
```

Update on __ Problem 2 __
I tried different sizes for the input string and I found this:
After about 650 calls to the device driver, with a size of 3.3k, the message list size becomes 4MiB (which is the maximum). A few more calls are made to the device and then the kernel freezes.

**EDIT 1**: I updated te dev_write as per comment and deleted debug code
**EDIT 2**: Added some more functions: push/pop/destroy
**EDIT 3**: I put in the check for buffer length vs message length

Comment: "If I write a C program that handles the fd in dev_write" ?? this does not mean much to me ... Also, head will (should) call dev_read (head reads from the file). And more, the kernel provides a working and well tested linked list which you can find in linux/list.h in kernel sources, do not implement another one, use existing one instead.

Comment: @NathaelPajani, I put the code for my reader from device. I mean this outputs the message that dev_read copies from kernel space to user space. `head -n 1 < /dev/opensysmem` does not. dev_read is called (the message is taken out from the list, but nothing is printed to the user. (PS I tried adding a newline in the message passed to the kernel and read it, but still nothing)

Comment: dev_write() must do a copy_from_user() before doing the push() - you cannot pass the buffer/len received from dev_write() to copy_to_user() in dev_read() - that data is still in user space ... (read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12666493/why-do-you-have-to-use-copy-to-user-copy-from-user-to-access-user-space-from)); other comments: in dev_read(), you don't check that message_length is <= len; also, in both dev_read() and dev_write() you ignore the offset argument - maybe the "head" program uses seek for some things? also "head" will need to see an end-of-line char (i.e. newline).

Comment: @MurrayJensen I would accept that as an answer if you do a write-up. I was totally new to copying memory from kernel space to user space and vice-versa. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think **Problem 1** may be either because `head` is not seeing an end-of-line character (e.g. newline,`'\n'`), or it uses seek system calls and you ignore the `offset` argument in your `dev_read()` and `dev_write()` functions (which means seeks won't work, if I understand it correctly) ... check [this](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/head.c) out - head does try to optimise things using seeks, but not sure if it applies in your case.

Also not sure your answer about **Problem 2** being caused by time being out of sync is correct (unless it has something to do with `msleep()`) ... my guess would be memory allocation problems or a race condition but you don't show us the source code for `push()` and `pop()` so we can't tell.

It looks like you just store the `buffer` and `len` arguments from `dev_write()` and then use them in `dev_read()` to pass to `copy_to_user()` ... the data in that buffer will still be in user space, so you could be attempting to copy from user space to user space. Reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12666493/why-do-you-have-to-use-copy-to-user-copy-from-user-to-access-user-space-from) might help.

You should update your question with the code of `push()` and `pop()` ... but at a minimum `push()` will need to allocate memory for both a linked list element to be inserted in the list and for a buffer to hold the write data, then use `copy_from_user()` to get the data out of user space and into the kernel buffer ... and then, after you have finished with `msg` in `dev_read()`, you will need to free the kernel buffer contained in `msg` and then free `msg` itself.

A lot of copying going on here I know, but to avoid this you have to work very hard with the virtual memory system and the design of your code (i.e. a *Zero Copy* implementation).

One more small but very important thing, in `dev_read()` you don't check that `message_length` is `<= len` i.e. that there is enough space for the message in the buffer. For example, as your code stands, your driver potentially could try to copy a message bigger than the space available. `copy_to_user()` should catch this, but then again maybe this is the source of your **Problem 2**.

Comment: I created a separate thread for the problem of deallocating the memory. I think it's a whole different issue. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/553500/kernel-space-memory-deallocation-freezes-kernel

Comment: Also, in my implementation, I do exactly what you said. Take a look at the other issue.

Comment: I implemented a lot of fixes from your text and I found the issue with __Problem 2__. Problem 1 has now evolved into a new topic. I will mark this as solved.

Answer (score 0):

I solved **Problem 2**. It was occurring because virtualbox was getting out of sync with the host machine.

Found the solution here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308492/virtualbox-synchronisation-problems

It is:

> VBoxManage guestproperty set  "/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/VBoxService/--timesync-set-threshold" 1000

Answer (score 0):

**Problem 1**

I searched my commit history and I found a commit message saying "Working test.sh" which means it was passing the write with `echo` and reading with `head -n 1`

In this commit, my dev_read function is returning the message length.

This seems to work for both `head -n 1` and `cat` and buffered read from the mentioned C program.

I found the answer here:
https://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.4/html/c577.htm